# What is the correct pattern to display UITableView data in a UITabBarController?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to display some (hard coded for now) data in a UITableView that is inside a UITabBarController, but I have having difficulty filling the rows.

Here is the code for my data object (Reservation.swift)

```
import UIKit

class Reservation: NSObject {
    var tailNumber: String
    var aircraftType: String
    var arrivalTime: String
    var eta: String

    init(tailNumber: String, aircraftType: String, arrivalTime: String, eta: String) {
        self.tailNumber = tailNumber
        self.aircraftType = aircraftType
        self.arrivalTime = arrivalTime
        self.eta = eta

        super.init()
    }
}
```

Here is the code to my Reservation Store (ReservationStore.swift)

```
import UIKit

class ReservationStore {
    // Store all our schedules
    var allReservations = [Reservation]()

    func createReservation() -> Reservation {
        let newReservation = Reservation(tailNumber: "N53440", aircraftType: "C172S", arrivalTime: "07-06-2016 07:00am", eta: "1:58")

        allReservations.append(newReservation)

        return newReservation
    }

    init() {
        createReservation()
    }
}
```

and here is my UITableView view controller (ScheduleViewController.swift)

```
import UIKit

class ScheduleViewController: UITableViewController {
    var reservationStore: ReservationStore!

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return reservationStore.allReservations.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("UITableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        let item = reservationStore.allReservations[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = item.tailNumber

        return cell
}

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let reservationStore = ReservationStore()

        let tabController = segue.destinationViewController as! UITabBarController
        let reservationController = tabController.viewControllers![1] as! ScheduleViewController

        reservationController.reservationStore = reservationStore
    }   
}
```

I'm receiving a fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value on return reservationStore.allReservations.count

I believe that prepareForSegue is called as the user clicks the UITabController item for the schedule and right before the view loads. This should trigger the init() in my ReservationStore and create one element in the array but I don't believe that is happening because it's nil by the time the array is counted?

Maybe this creation should be in the prepareForSegue? Been messing with this for a day or so not sure where to head next, could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prepareForSegue()` is not called before the view loads.  It's called when *that* view controller is preparing to segue to a *new* view controller.  There's nothing assigning to your `ScheduleViewController`'s `reservationStore` property, so it's `nil`, hence the crash.

If all you want to do is have an instance of `ReservationStore` assigned to that property, you can just set it as the default value when defining the property:

```
class ScheduleViewController: UITableViewController {
    var reservationStore = ReservationStore()

    // …
}
```

Comment: Ah hah! Thank you!